# Loading records in a table. Browser not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

From ajax call I am getting 1000+ `tr` for a `table` `body`. And when i am load that data into `table` body

Loading records is a `table` `body`.

```
$('#loadingRecords').html(data);
```

The browser hangs and not responding for a while. What is the best way when we working with that kind of problem ?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: load less and run faster by paginating the rows: nobody can see 1000 at once anyway...

Comment: Try getting the data in an asynchronous manner and do pagination.

Answer (score 0):

The browser hangs because you are performing a heavy operation on the DOM. This can be alleviated by using [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination), or by performing the operation in smaller batches by splitting the results into smaller chunks.

Comment: @Sunila, what is not working? What have you tried? Please elaborate more if you want to be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping the HTML data into a hidden `table` tag. Then after it is done, show it.

The problem is with redraws. Each table manipulation causes the entire thing to become 'dirty'. Hence the browser has to do a redraw.